# Como crear un boton sin icono en CKEditor

Tags: javascript, laravel, ckeditor

Estoy utilizando `CKEditor` para poder trabajar de forma más comoda los textos en mi proyecto de `laravel`. Y estoy personalizando un nuevo boton en mi `CKEditor` para que realice una función en específico; el botón personalizado me quedo de la siguiente forma:

```
let editor = CKEDITOR.replace('asuntos_generales');

editor.addCommand("mySimpleCommand", {
    exec: function(edt) {
        alert(edt.getData());
    }
});
editor.ui.addButton('SuperButton', {
        label: "Agregar Acuerdo",
        title: 'Agregar Acuerdo',
        command: 'mySimpleCommand',
        toolbar: 'insert',
        /*icon: 'https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/5500999?v=2&s=16'*/
       
});
```

pero la idea es que no me aparezca un ícono en el botón sino que me aparezca por ejemplo esto: `Agregar`. me puede ayudar con algunas ideas

Comment: Abre un editor de imágenes, (paint, paintbrush, etc), escribe el texto en letra pequeña, 8 a 10px. limita el tamaño a envolver convenientemente el texto, no olvides ponerle fondo transparente y. Guarda con formato .png (gráfica vectorial) ubicalo convenientemente en tu estructura de directorios y asigna su url al atributo icon.

Comment: pero no hay forma de poner un texto? porque ahí lo que estoy es poniéndole una imagen al final

Comment: No lo se. Pero es una solución mientras encuentras en la documentación cual es el atributo a asignar. Si mal no recuerdo CKaos creó el CKeditor que se usa en las versiones 6 y 7 de Drupal. Si examinas el código del módulo para Drupal seguramente encuentres el atributo. Se que usas Laravel, pero, en esencia se trata de un(os) bloque(s) de código servidos usando php.

Answer (score 0):

Solo necesitas agregar un par de estilos para lograr lo que buscas:

```
<style>
.cke_button_icon.cke_button__superbutton_icon { display:none; }
.cke_button_label.cke_button__superbutton_label { display:inline; }
</style>
```

El primero es para ocultar el icono, como no existe, no tiene caso dejar espacio en blanco. El segundo es para mostrar el texto. Resultado:

```js
let editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' );
editor.addCommand("mySimpleCommand", {
    exec: function(edt) {
            alert(edt.getData());
    }
});
editor.ui.addButton('SuperButton', {
    label: "Agregar",          // Nombre como deseas que aparezca en el botón
    title: 'Agregar Acuerdo',  // Lo que aparece al colocar el cursor sobre el botón
    command: 'mySimpleCommand',
    toolbar: 'insert',
});
```

```css
.cke_button_icon.cke_button__superbutton_icon { display:none; }
.cke_button_label.cke_button__superbutton_label { display:inline; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.15.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<textarea id="editor"></textarea>
```

En caso de no estar usando la versión 4.x, usa el *Inspector* del navegador para buscar el elemento y ver qué clases son las que necesitas agregar o modificar:

[image: Inspeccionando elementos]

**Nota:** El editor no funciona en el fragmento de código por problemas CORS, pero ahí ya se ve el botón.